# Data entry SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok so I've created my database in SQLite in android but it is a readble only, I wanted to input my information into the tables to add functions to it in Android.

There are many tutorials on how to do this through the application at runtime, but how can you have the table information already in the app when the user loads the application?

Im sure many of you will recommend this http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

This is good but it doesnt support foreign keys...

I know you can do it this way, but I have a lot of information.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBAdapter.Column1,  "HP");
    values.put(DBAdapter.Column2,  "qw");
    values.put(DBAdapter.Column3,  "5280");
    values.put(DBAdapter.Column4,  "345, 546");
    db.insert(DBAdapter.TABLE, null, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys is there. You need to remove this line from the dump:

`PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF`; and violà! You have your foreign keys.

All you have to do is this:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```

when you create your DB. By-default, it is off and you won't get the foreign keys when you switch it on. Want some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just execute insert statements in your class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper? Something like this:

```
public class DataStore extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // execute create
            // execute insert
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> but how can you have the table information already in the app when the user loads the application?

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, DATA);
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
}
```